# Why isn't the version of the NebulaGraph displayed after running the show hosts graph COMMAND?

Tags: database, graph-theory, graph-databases, nebula-graph

I encountered a problem using the Nebula Graph graph database. I want to check the version installed, and I read the doc and ran the show hosts graph command. But the graph version wasn't displayed.

[image]

I tried other commands like `show hosts` and `show hosts storage`, but it didn't help.

Can you tell me what should I do to help me check the version of the graph service? I will appreciate it.

Comment: As @Lisa Liu answered so, we could always check the version from the service binary with `--version`, too

```bash
/usr/local/nebula/bin/nebula-graphd --version
nebula-graphd version 2021.07.28-nightly, Git: c6f702de, Build Time: Jul 29 2021 03:26:04
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 2.x or non-release version, the graph service version isn't displayed.